# Pandas: joining specific columns of one data frame to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 following data frames in pandas:

**movies**

```
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
|   | movie title                  | genre        | tconst    |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 0 | Edison Kinetoscopic Record   | Documentary  | tt0000008 |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1 | La sortie des usines Lumière | Documentary  | tt0000010 |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2 | The Arrival of a Train       | Documentary  | tt0000012 |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 3 | The Oxford and Cambridge     | NaN          | tt0000025 |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 4 | Le manoir du diable          | Short|Horror | tt0000091 |
+---+------------------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

and **crew**

```
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
|   | tconst    | directors | writers | year |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
| 0 | tt0000001 | nm0005690 | \N      | 2001 |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
| 1 | tt0000002 | nm0721526 | \N      | 2002 |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
| 2 | tt0000003 | nm0721526 | \N      | 2003 |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
| 3 | tt0000004 | nm0721526 | \N      | 2004 |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
| 4 | tt0000005 | nm0005690 | \N      | 2005 |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------+------+
```

How do I create a new data frame where I join **directors** and **year** columns only to **movies** data frame (using tconst column) ?

Comment: Could you possibly reformat the post to display your df's properly? It is hard to follow and it may make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry, was pretty sure I did everything correct, but the table still looked bad

Comment: Good answer below!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.merge(movies, crew[["tconst", "directors", "year"]], on="tconst", how="left")
```

the `on` parameter tells the function that you want to merge on the key `tconst`, the `how` parameter tells the function how you want to deal with rows that aren't intersections (shared) between the two DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.